# Why does the depletion region penetrate more into the lightly doped region in a pn junction?

Tags: pn-junction

I have read at several places if we take exact same cubes of p and and n doped semiconductor material and form a junction, the depletion region(blue colored region in my drawing) will be asymmetric around the physical center as below:

[image]

This means for some reason the doping difference in two materials shows itself in such asymmetry.

If correct, how could it be explained in simple terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple enough — if you want to transfer some number of carriers from one side to the other in order to neutralize them, they must be more spread out (occupy a greater volume) on the lightly-doped side.

The doping level refers to the density of donor or acceptor atoms in the semiconductor matrix; light doping means a lower density.

Comment: Do you mean the majority carries in n side diffuse more inside the p side because their number is more than the majority carriers of p side? (assuming n side is highly doped as in the question)

Answer (score 2):

The total space charge must be 0 so that no E field extends beyond the depletion region. Therefore the total space charge on the two sides must be equal and opposite. Therefore space charge volume must be greater on the more lightly doped side.

Comment: why exactly is the space charge zero at the n/p-layers? Isn't there a surplus of charge carriers?

Comment: @Ben, The depletion region is the region around the junction where the mobile carriers have been swept away. The space charge is formed by the remaining fixed carriers (donor and acceptor ions). The total space charge on the two sides of the depletion region must net to zero. Otherwise there would be (by Gauss's law) an E-field extending beyond the depletion region. Which would push around the mobile carriers and make the depletion region grow wider.

Comment: Thank you! But when there are fixed carriers (positive ions on the side and negative ions on the other side) then why is the space charge zero? Because they cancel out each other (only possible in case of a current, is it?)?

Comment: @Ben, If I have +1 uC on one side and -1 uC on the other side, the sum of those charges is zero whether there is a current flowing or not.

Comment: ah, that's easy :) I misunderstood it such that each layer itself must be neutral. So only the net/overall space charge must be neutral.